# Grouping vs separate glVertex in immediate mode

Tags: opengl

I know they are deprecated, but are these 2 equivalent?

1.

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(x1, y1);
glVertex2f(x1, y2);
glVertex2f(x1, y2);
glVertex2f(x2, y2);
glVertex2f(x1, y1);
glVertex2f(x2, y1);
glVertex2f(x2, y1);
glVertex2f(x2, y2);
glEnd();
```

2.

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(x1, y1);
glVertex2f(x1, y2);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(x1, y2);
glVertex2f(x2, y2);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(x1, y1);
glVertex2f(x2, y1);
glEnd();

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(x2, y1);
glVertex2f(x2, y2);
glEnd();
```

Comment: They are not "deprecated". They are removed from core OpenGL 3.2+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalent in behavior? Yes.

Equivalent in performance? No. Sure, you're dealing with immediate mode, so it's going to be slow. But even for immediate mode, there's slow and there's *slow*. The fewer `glBegin` calls you need to make, the better.